# How Can I assign the SnapshotChanges in a Observable Firebase Variable?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I want to load all the data of a document, but I can not access the id of the document. When i print the object this.ressobj the id is visible, but when i put the ressobj.id_doc in the card the id id of the document is not visible.

```js
this.ResColeccion = this.resser.getSpecificlistRestaurants(this.id);
     this.ResObservable$ = this.ResColeccion.snapshotChanges().subscribe(usuariolista =>{
    this.ressobj=usuariolista.map(res =>{
 return{
   nombre:res.payload.doc.data().nombre,
   logo:res.payload.doc.data().logo,
   descripcion:res.payload.doc.data().descripcion,
   portada:res.payload.doc.data().portada,
   idadmin:res.payload.doc.data().idadmin,
   id_doc:res.payload.doc.id
 }
 
        });
        console.log(this.ressobj);
        
      });
```

HTML CODE

```js
<ion-card *ngFor="let ressobj of ResObservable$ | async " [routerLink]="['/opcionesrestaurante',ressobj.id_doc]"  >
    
       
      
        <img src="{{ressobj.portada}}">
  
       
     <ion-card-content>
       
    
        <ion-card-title>
            <h1>{{ressobj.nombre}}</h1>
        </ion-card-title> 
      <p>{{ressobj.descripcion}}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but I've used something like that for my angularfire2 projects:

Getting a document:

```
const ResObservable$ = () => {
        return this.ResColeccion
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              const data = actions.payload.data() as any;
              const uid = actions.payload.id;
              return { uid, ...data};
            })
          );
    }

ResObservable$.subscribe(item => console.log(item)) // or use async
```

Getting a collection:

```
const ResObservable$ = () => {
    return this.ResColeccion
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
            const uid = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { uid, ...data };
          });
        })
      );
}

ResObservable$.subscribe(items => console.log(items)) // or use async pipe
```

Comment: what export that i need for use map?

Comment: that's an rxjs operator : `import { map }  from 'rxjs/operators'`